# How to get the string with special char $ and '

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I have a basic question but not able to figure it out how to do this.

I need to frame a command string with a password from a C file and need to execute that command.I am using Linux.

what I am doing is

```
sprintf(command, "mycommand with password=$passw'ord");
system(command);
```

The issue what I am facing is when I am using `'` during the command execution as follow
`'$passw\'ord'` ,it is not working.

when tried as follow

`sprintf(command, "mycommand with password='$passw\'ord'");` //not working it showing `>` in the terminal and showing  error as unterminated `'`

but when passing only `'$password'` is working ,but I need to pass the `'` character also.

To try we can use

```
echo  '$password' //working
echo  '$passw\\'ord' //Not working
```

Is there any thing for this.

Comment: What about `"mycommand with password=\"$passw'ord\""`?

Comment: It may be easier to use `fork`+`exec*` instead of `system`. Then you don't need to worry about escaping characters for the shell.

Comment: Refer the [Bash quoting rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Except the single-quote (`'`) character, everything else can be included inside a single-quoted string and with no escapes. [Bash makes no special interpretation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html#Single-Quotes) of single-quoted strings and and just passes through the literal characters.

Remember that mixing single and double-quoted strings freely is supported. Thus

```
$ echo 'my command with password=$passw'"'"'ord'
my command with password=$passw'ord
```

works. In *C* this would translate into

```
char const *cmd = "'my command with password=$passw'\"'\"'ord'";
```

Comment: Is that means we can't use \' in the string to escape that..??

Comment: It means you needn't need to escape anything inside `'` so write everything except `'` inside `' '`; now when you've to put a `'` inside it, use a `""` double-quoted string. Having single and double-quoted strings following each other is valid. This is what is done in the answer.